# Angular js- Simulate browser back/forward button disabling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pushstate

I am working on application which requires me to simulate browser back/forward button(I have implemented 2 buttons). I am able to achieve this functionality using `window.history.forward()` and `window.history.back()`. The functionality works as desired.
But i have one issue i have requirement of disabling forward button when there are no more pages to browse further and vice versa for back button.

I have tried using following workarounds, but nothing works.

```
if(!window.history.next){
    $scope.abcService.enableForwardButton = false;
}
```

This `if` condition never gets satisfied, even if I dont have any pages to browse further.

```
var index = window.history.length;
if(window.history[index] != window.location)
{
    $scope.abcService.enableForwardButton = true;
}
```

Any inputs will be helpful.
Note: disabling the buttons is mandatory requirement for the application

Comment: You should use the $window service, not the window directly.

Comment: forward should always be disabled, unless you clicked back before clicking anything else. so, disable forward on every nav, and unlock only after a back command on a short setTimeout.

Comment: I can enable the forward button on click of back button, but i am more concerned about how would i determine if its last page and then disable forward button when no more pages are available to browse further.

Comment: if you using angular, get $state.current.name and disable under if block, if ($state.current.name=='lastPage'){toDo()}

Comment: What if user comes to your pages from some other web page? Then he will have the record in window.history and when he clicks the Back button he leave your application. Is that a desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The $location service may be of use to you. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#state

Also, I'm not sure how compatible it would be with angular, but you may want to look at https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/

Answer (score -1):

I believe this should work for you.

```
if(typeof window.history.forward!=='function'){
  $scope.abcService.enableForwardButton = false;
}
```

When you can navigate forward then typeof window.history.forward is 'function' when you cannot then it is 'undefined'